# Scroll not working properly in AppBarLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have this layout and on scrolling down everything works fine: the upper TextView and the ImageView are scrolling and the bottom TextView remains always pinned, but when I barely scroll I expect that the upper TextView appears and instead of this a part of ImageView(I guess it's the TextView's height) shows up. I want the image to appear only when the user reached the top of the layout. So how do I fix this problem? Am I missing something?
    [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09JCq.jpg)

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:text="View which must show up when scrolling starts"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="#aa0a2f"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="pinned view">

            </TextView></android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You want to achive like [this](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) or use NestedScrollView in your code

Comment: I want to achieve something alike, but not totally similar. I need the first (upper) TextView to show up on scrolling up and the ImageView to appear only when user reached the top

Comment: Now that's strange, i implemented your layout this effect. Before scrolling the upper text view is visible, as we scroll down first the upper text view then the image view disappear and the pinned view is still visible. If this is the effect you are going for then it must be something you are doing in your code that causes the problem. If not can you show us an image example of what you want.

Comment: I get this effect too, but I also want that on scrolling up the upper textview to appear and then the image to appear only when user reached the top